# Operator norm of $\frac{x^TW^Tx\cdot I-Wxx^T}{||Wx||^2}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

Let $x\in S^{d}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d \mid \| x\|=1\}$ and $W\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ how tight can we bound $\sigma_{\max} \left(\frac{x^TW^Tx\cdot I-Wxx^T}{||Wx||^2}\right)$ with respect to $\lambda_\min(W)$ and $\lambda_{max}(W)$?

Answer (score 1):

Operator norm is infinite. Take $W$ such that $\|W\|=1$ and $x$ is the right eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda<1$

$$Wx=\lambda x$$

Applying operator gives you the following matrix with norm $1/\lambda$
$$\frac{I-xx'}{\lambda}$$

Comment: Correct. That said, I am looking for bounds on $\sigma_{max}$ that are allowed to depend on $\lambda(W)$. So while $\sigma_{max}$ is unbounded as $\lambda\rightarrow 0$, I am uncertain this argument shows $\sigma_{max}$ is unbounded as a function of $\lambda$. I updated the question to clarify this, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: For example, in the case where $||W||=1$ and $x$ is a right eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda<1$, we get that if $\lambda_{min}(W)>1/2$ applying the operator gives us a matrix with operator norm $> 2$. I am uncertain whether this special case of eigenvector caries over to the general case of any $x$.

Comment: You could bound lambda_min from below, (which makes it weird to call it an "operator norm" since it makes W's not closed under scalar multiplication, see 2.5.2 of Bhatia's http://www.cmat.edu.uy/~lessa/tesis/Positive%20Definite%20Matrices.pdf). In such case take W with lambda_min's eigenvector corresponding to x.